# Custom Sort of a SharePoint List based on Values in two different Columns

Tags: sorting, sharepoint

I have two columns based on which sorting needs to be done. Column 1: Priority Column 2: Ageing.

Sorting 1st needs to be done by checking columns 1. If the Priority is ASAP those items need to show 1st and then it needs to sort based on column 2 where the ageing is highest. Items to this list will be added continously.

I have tried to create a workflow and do not see the option for the same.

Any suggestions.

Regards,
Renato.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the default sorting of a list view ? It seems fitting your needs.

[image]

In first sort column, you set Priority and in the second, you set Ageing, no ?

Edit : You can't use this solution since you need some logic in your sort.

In this case, I propose to use an Event Receiver and a custom column. Let's say we name this column "Position". This solution needs some knowledge in development.

Your column position'll store an integer. This integer'll be calculated by the logic you put in the Event Receiver. At the end, your list'll be sorted with the column position.

And in the Event Receiver, your job is to calculate the position of all your item every time there is a change so :

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    this.EventFiringEnabled = false; //Prevent the Event Receiver to fire twice
    SPList list = properties.ListItem.Parent;
    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(); //Get all items or use some query to get the items you want to retrieve 
    try
    {
        SetOrder(items); //This function define the column position
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //LOG
    }
    finally
    {
        this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
    }
}

private void SetOrder(SPListItemCollection items)
{
    //Here reorder items in your list by setting the column position according to your needs.
}
```

Comment: Hi, When i use default sort i am unable to set my values like, ASAP, HOT, High, Medium. Next sorting needs to happen based on the ageing Hot is next in the priority, if the ageing of the medium priority is higher than Hot it should immediately after ASAP.

Comment: Ah ok. I got this needs some times ago. I used a custom column where i stored my order. This order was calculated by an Event Receiver which used the business logic that i defined.

Comment: Thibault could you share how you did it.